# How do you import a class from a different module in python

Tags: python-3.x

This is the error I am getting. What am I doing wrong here,  im very new to python as i said in my last question, any advice/help will be greatly appreciated thank you.
All the python files related to this are in the same folder so im not sure whats causing this? what i read a second ago said something about the name of my file or something but ive changed it quite a few times and still get the same error.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Student\Desktop\python-ig\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from GTA import gta_post_request
  File "C:\Users\Student\Desktop\python-ig\GTA.py", line 3, in <module>
    from MS import MultiSession
ImportError: cannot import name 'MultiSession' from 'MS' (C:\Users\Student\Desktop\python-ig\MS.py
```

and this is the code that is supposed to replace the session.get or session.post with multi_session.get or multi_session.post

```
import requests
import json

class MultiSession:
    def __init__(self, session_cookie_file):
        self.session_cookie_file = session_cookie_file
        self.sessions = self.load_sessions()

    def load_sessions(self):
        with open(self.session_cookie_file, "r") as file:
            session_cookies = json.load(file)

        sessions = []

        for cookie in session_cookies:
            session = requests.Session()
            session.cookies.update(cookie)
            sessions.append(session)

        return sessions

    def get(self, url, **kwargs):
        responses = []
        for session in self.sessions:
            response = session.get(url, **kwargs)
            responses.append(response)
        return responses

    def post(self, url, data=None, json=None, **kwargs):
        responses = []
        for session in self.sessions:
            response = session.post(url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
            responses.append(response)
        return responses
```

I honestly havent tried anything to fix it as I cant at all figure out why I can not import this.
I just read something someone asked about this already but I didnt get a clear enough answer for me to understand, I dont do well with understanding instructions so best option to help me is to give an example.

Comment: Are you sure there are no circular imports involved here? `MS.py` doesn't try to import stuff from `GTA` or `main` or the like?

Comment: nvm i fixed that error sorry guys! it was just the name was apparently in the python search path or what ever sorry!

Comment: @ShadowRanger there werent any circular imports  but its just there was already a module named MS and a module named multi_session in python. but now im getting a list error for every file since there are more then one session cookies in the file i will post another question if i cant figure this out thank you for the speedy response! Ill be getting back to you !

Comment: Neither of those are built-in modules, sounds like you probably littered your system with multiple versions of your source code in various states of development and got bitten. C'est la vie.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do

```
from ms import MultiSession
```

What I needed to do was change the file name so I changed it to

```
from dupe import MultiSession
```

This worked for my issue but it may not work for everyone.

Comment: It might be of interest for future readers to know how you figured this out.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When you cannot import an object from another module, although the object was defined in it's source file, it could happen that the incorrect file was loaded. To find out from which file the module was actually imported, you can check its `__file__` attribute:

```
import MS
print(MS.__file__)
```